# Scala - How to merge incremental files of HDFS location

Tags: scala, shell, file, apache-spark, hdfs

My requirement is that I've a multiple HDFS location which ingest files from Kafka every hour. So for each directory how to merge all the files of a particular timestamp to current timestamp as a single parquet file and next time merge the files from last merged timestamp to current timestamp only, and repeat the same in future. This all I have to do in Spark Scala job so can't go with normal shell script.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Show an example as a little hard to follow

Comment: Look into delta lake

Comment: Do you need to merge the files from across directories or merge has to be done only within directories ? How often you want to run the merge ? I

Comment: Hi @Sugesh, From any specific directory I want to merge all the hdfs files of a day (according to unix timestamp for the files) as single files, means if 1000 files are available for 1 month, then total 30/31 files should be as output merged files, one file for each day. please suggest the way.

Comment: But I want to do it using Spark Scala and not by Shell/Unix script.

Comment: Have given a code snippet that should work for you. Please do a test and tweak as per your finite requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet that would help to get the thing done.

First step is to the get the list of files per date as a Map. `(Map[String, List[String]])` where key is Date and value is list of files with a same date. Date is taken from the modification timestamp of the HDFS file.

Note: Tested the code using local path, give the right HDFS path / url as required.

While writing the output, there is no direct option to specify the target filename, but you can specify the target directory specific to each date. Code makes us FileSystem APIs to rename the file to the desired and delete the temp output folders created per date.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileStatus, FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat


object MergeFiles {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("Merging files day wise in a directory")
      .master("local[2]")
      .getOrCreate()

    val inputDir = "/Users/sujesh/test_data"
    val outputDir = "/Users/sujesh/output_data"

    val hadoopConf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
    val fs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConf)

    val filesPerDate = getFiles(inputDir, fs)

    filesPerDate
      .foreach { m =>
        spark
          .read
          .format("csv")
          .option("inferSchema", false)
          .option("header", false)
          .load(m._2:_*)
          .repartition(1)
          .write
          .format("csv")
          .save(s"$outputDir/${m._1}")

        val file = fs.globStatus(new Path(s"$outputDir/${m._1}/part*.csv"))(0).getPath.getName
        fs.rename(new Path(s"$outputDir/${m._1}/$file"), new Path(s"$outputDir/${m._1}.csv"))
        fs.delete(new Path(s"$outputDir/${m._1}"), true)
      }
  }

  /*
    Get the list of files group by date
    date is taken from file's modification timestamp
   */
  def getFiles(dir: String, fs: FileSystem) = {
    fs
      .globStatus(new Path(s"$dir/*.csv"))
      .map { f: FileStatus =>
        (DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd").print(f.getModificationTime), f.getPath.toUri.getRawPath)
       }.groupBy(_._1)
       .map { case (k,v) => (k -> v.map(_._2).toSeq) }
  }
}
```

You may further optimise the code after tests and convert the file rename code to a util if it has to be re-used. Have put all options such as `inferSchema` or `header` to false. Use them as you need. This approach should work for other formats of files too.

Note: If you are repeatedly doing this process in the same directory, further tweaks would be required as the newly created files will have the latest timestamp. Hence if this is not run daily, you need to explicitly update the modification timestamp of the file too or ignore the files having a pattern of file name such as `yyyyMMdd.csv`

Comment: Hi @Sujesh, I am trying to connect with my hdfs (dev env.) cluster and get the hdfs files with their processed timestamp according to your given code, but I'm not able to connect. getting error that hdfs path not found which starts with 'hdfs://........'.

Comment: are you able to run hdfs commands and access the files from where you run this code ?